# jQuery DatePicker - Focus Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

`<input type="text" id="personDOB" data-autofill="Under 18,N/A" />`

```
$("#personDOB").datetimepicker({
    showOtherMonths : true,
    selectOtherMonths : true,
    changeMonth : true,
    changeYear : true,
    showButtonPanel : true
});
```

My current work around is : `buttonImageOnly: true`,

Using an icon rather than on focus...

The above is the text field and the date picker code.

Also using time addon: https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

I notice the date picker shows on foucs, but only want it to show on click..

I've tried having a look through source code but cant seem to come out with a hack.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not able to make out your problem??

Comment: Datetime picker is been shown on focus, I only want to shwo it on click

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ this example is shown on click, is that what you need?

Comment: Yes but if you go on that page and run $('#datepicker').focus(); which is code to focus that text feild it shows it as well, i only want to show it on click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to attach datetimepicker on click event and then show it:

```
$(function() {
    $("#personDOB").click(function() {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
        // .....
        }).datetimepicker("show");
    });
});
```

This would work for datepicker, but I am not sure it works for this datetimepicker.